# Set MySQL Column Alias to a Calculated Date

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
select data AS curdate() from table;
```

so the resulting table would look like:

```
2013-04-26
  data 1
  data 2
  data 3
```

I can't figure out the syntax, but it must be possible?

I've tried it without quotes of any kind, which returns an error. Single quotes and back ticks both return the SQL itself as the column header.

Comment: I doubt this is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an unusual requirement, but if you insist, you'd have to use dynamic sql.

```
SET @curdate = CURDATE();
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT whatever AS "', @curdate, '" FROM whatever');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Looks correct to me but when i ran, got this error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2013-04-26 FROM users limit 10' at line 1 (`SET @qry = CONCAT('SELECT uid AS ', @curdate, ' FROM users limit 10');`)

Comment: @Sumoanand Added `"`, that should fix this.

Comment: Oh, i should have caught it. :)  +1

Answer (score 0):

An alias is considered an identifier and cannot be assigned to a function without the use of dynamic SQL. It would break referencing such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 AS curdate()) a
```