# Dynamical alias from date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, variables, date, dynamic, alias

i would like to make dynamic alias from dates as you can se below. Everyday will be the name of column different. I tried it with variable but it doesn't work. The solution should be something like below or if i dont need to use variables it can be possible too.

```
SET @today = CURRENT_DATE(),
    @lastWeek = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL -7 DAY);

SELECT date1 AS @today, date2 AS @lastweek FROM table1;
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have You tried `PREPARE STMT` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243137/set-mysql-column-alias-to-a-calculated-date). I think that's what you need.

So you could do:

```
SET @today = CURRENT_DATE(),
    @lastWeek = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL -7 DAY),
    @sql = concat('SELECT date1 AS "', @today, '", date2 AS "', @lastweek, '" FROM table1');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I tried it but maybe you have there two mistakes. One is on second row, there should be comma in the end. And in the concat function i think there should be apostrophe before 'SELECT statement and on the end after FROM table1'. After these corrections it works.

Comment: Ah sorry for the mistakes (corrected them), was in a hurry but I'm glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked like a charm to give me dynamic date columns.

```
SET @today = CURRENT_DATE(),
    @day1 = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL -1 DAY),
    @day2 = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL -2 DAY),
    @day3 = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL -3 DAY),
    @day4 = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL -4 DAY),
    @day5 = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL -5 DAY),
    @sql = concat("SELECT JRR_RESULT, COUNT(LEFT(JRR_RESULT,40)) AS 'Total Error Last 
5 Days'"
    ", sum(IF( DATE_FORMAT(CREATION_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') = '" , @day1, "',1,0) ) AS '", 
@day1, "' "
    ", sum(IF( DATE_FORMAT(CREATION_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') = '" , @day2, "',1,0) ) AS '", 
@day2, "' "
    ", sum(IF( DATE_FORMAT(CREATION_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') = '" , @day3, "',1,0) ) AS '", 
@day3, "' "
    ", sum(IF( DATE_FORMAT(CREATION_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') = '" , @day4, "',1,0) ) AS '", 
@day4, "' "
    ", sum(IF( DATE_FORMAT(CREATION_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') = '" , @day5, "',1,0) ) AS '", 
@day5, "' "
    " FROM your_table where DATE_FORMAT(CREATION_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '" , @day5, "' "
    " Group by LEFT(JRR_RESULT,40)"); 

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```